# Update YAML file with ansible

Tags: filebeat

I am trying to deploy and configure Filebeat on large number of linux machines. Deployment is OK but I do not know how I can update filebeat.yml on the fly. For example I want to put
filebeat.inputs:
id: $HOSTNAME-filebeat
Where $HOSTNAME is the name of the system where this filebeat is deployed. How I can do that. Ansible does not have an easy way to to do that.

Comment: do you mean , using the fact : inventory_hostname or ansible_hostname ? 
https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-inventory_hostname-ansible_hostname-variables/